# Was reverting this edit correct?

Tags: discussion, editing

I noticed [this edit](https://space.stackexchange.com/revisions/24496/2) and thought it was questionable.  Several of the substitutions didn't even seem technically correct--e.g. "burning plasma" and "half combusted".  However, the edit was approved by two reviewers, so I wanted to draw attention to my action and get it checked.

Seems like I should disclose that I wouldn't have even noticed except that the user who penned the edit has made a lot of contributions recently and gotten most of them heavily-downvoted, so I was curious when I saw them pop up in question activity on something with positive votes.  It's possible I'm just being biased.  At the moment, I read the edit as generally worse though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IMHO you did the right thing. I was surprised at some of the very questionable edits that got approved recently.

Actually, I'd like to thank you for taking this action to improve the quality of the site. In recent days the site seems to have been swarmed by illiterates, cheaters, and plagiarists, and I applaud any counter-actions.

Comment: I second this. I've seen some sketchy stuff flying under the radar and I can't catch all of it. Thanks to everyone for staying vigilant!