# Who is approving these edits?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

Similar to [Was reverting this edit correct?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2979/6944)

An edit to this question was just approved that contained gratuitous misspellings and use of all caps.  Is there some more sockpuppeting or something going on that is getting these edits approved?

[Does LOx stay as liquid when entering combustion chamber?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24842/6944)

I reverted this edit as well.

Comment: It looks like they're getting approved by new users with relatively poor track records themselves.

Comment: But they're not socks as far as I can tell.

Comment: @called2voyage thanks for checking

Comment: I have additionally added a 30 day edit ban to that specific user, based on their low quality posts/edits

Comment: @RoryAlsop that seems warranted. My main concern was that the built-in system of having other users approve the edits seemed to not be working in these 2 examples.

Comment: Agreed. It *should* but doesn't always

Comment: Do you have review audits here? (Unsure if they exist outside SO).

Comment: @user438383 Review audits are only active on a select few sites: [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: dunno what the necropost guidelines are in meta, but one user put through a glut of edits in the past 24 hours ish and they seemingly got approved without much attention getting paid to them.  The worst got reverted by uhoh already (it changed quotes from a source).  Seems like it's an issue still

Comment: @ErinAnne the sheer amount of low quality stuff being done here lately is quite frustrating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FYI, if you see a lot of these we can review and suspend a user from approving edits. It's a real pain to do, and it discourages involvement, but with a big enough list of badly approved edits we can look through them and see if a user should be banned from approving edits. I would personally only do it if the same user approved at least 2 really bad edits within a fairly short period of time, but it is an option.

For the edits from that particular user, there were 2 poor edits suggested and 4 different users who approved the edit, so far as I can tell. Hats off to the one user who rejected one of the bad edits!

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Sounds like it wouldn't help in this case. This makes me wonder if regular users (i.e. not mods) can see who approved the edits?

Comment: If you can, go to https://space.stackexchange.com/posts/24496/revisions and click on edit approved Aug 8 at 20:55. I'm quite sure we have more information than you will, but you might be able to see who approved at least. Now that I'm looking at it I can see some statistics that make the job easier.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info. I can see the list of names.

Comment: Unless foul play is likely, I'd message the user first before actually suspending them. Y'know, we are all volunteers.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica It's only a suspension of the ability to approve edits, not in the site in general. Still, warnings are usually preferred, I'll give you that.