# Is there a way to unapproved edits?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

After seeing this question [Who is approving these edits?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2981/who-is-approving-these-edits) I was quite surprised that my user was one of the users who approved that edit. Is there a way to unapproved it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always revert the edit, but I don't think you can cancel the approval in the first place... Reverts can happen by clicking on the time of the post and looking at the message history, then Rollback.