# Can a delay be added to the votes in the queue?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

There was [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/65180/looking-for-a-space-business-partner) which was in the queue of first question. I accidently clicked on "Looks ok". This was a mistake and I didn't mean to click this.

[image]
Since people always make a mistake every now and then, it seems like a good idea to allow people to change their votes in a short period.

Just like with the comments, you can still edit your comment up to 5 min after it has been posted.

Could there a delay be added before our votes are locked? Maybe we can change the voting system so that we can still change our votes after a couple of minutes.

Comment: I know that I asked a similar question https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2985/is-there-a-way-to-unapproved-edits but I really think there should be a method to retract votes if somebody misclicks

Comment: if you "really think there should be a method" maybe change this to a "feature-request" tagged request for something like the ability to change your recent vote within some short time period of them occurring, sort of like how comments can be edited for a brief window. There's obvious technical reasons that you shouldn't be able to change your vote at any time afterward (an action has to occur in response to the vote) but it seems like a good feature to request unless maybe that request already exists in the main StackExchange Meta (which I haven't checked)

Comment: @ErinAnne good idea, I will change the question

Comment: Since this would be a change to the overall SE software, it should be asked on the mother Meta site (but search first - lots of things have been requested and not done in the past).